# Undefined variable error with code for uploading images to database

Tags: php, sql, database

I am trying to create a code that will be able to upload and store an image to a database so I can then retrieve them on another page.

After watching a video on how to upload and stroe an image to a database I come up with an error indicating an Undefined variable: imageName, although I have initiated it and use it all over the code

Undefined variable: imageName

```
<?php
$pagetitle="Image Management";
session_start();
include_once('head.php');
include_once('stylesheets.php');
?>

</head>

<?php
include_once('navbar.php');
connectDB();
?>
<body>
<div class="container">

<form action ="NImageManagement.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="image"><input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
$imageName = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
$imageData = mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]));
$imageType = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["image"]["type"]);

if(substr($imageType,0,5) =="image")
    {
     mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'blob' VALUES('', '$imageName', '$imageData')");
     echo "Image Uploaded";
}else{
    echo "Only images are allowed!";
    }


?>
</div>


</body>
</html>
<?php
include_once('footer.php');
?>
```

I know that the code is not safe as it is but I plan to fix it after I have the main functions ready and working.
Any assistance on my problem will be greatly appreciated

Comment: What line do you get the error on?

Comment: line 28 mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'blob' VALUES('', '$imageName', '$imageData')");

Comment: I think you may be missing a {} after if(isset($_POST['submit'])) as you have placed your variables underneath your if statement, perhaps it can't recognise '$imageName'

Comment: @SohailArif You are right. that was what I was missing, thanks

Comment: You're welcome :) glad to be of assistance.